How to make Tensorflowjs converter work for .pb files?
I am trying to convert my .pb file (Frozen model format) to TensorFlow.js graph model format. I followed the instructions in the tfjs_converter documentation. So the command that I am running on my terminal is;
tensorflowjs_converter --input_format=tf_frozen_model --output_node_names='model/Softmax' ./model/moods_mirex-musicnn-msd-1.pb ./modeljs

But I keep getting the error;
KeyError: 'The name "\'model/Softmax\'" refers to an Operation not in the graph.'
To make sure the output_node_names argument that I'm using is correct, I used the netron visualization app. I believe it looks like the output node name should be indeed 'model/Softmax' , so I don't know what's wrong.
It shows here that the last layer node name is model/Softmax)
Am I doing something wrong?
Note: I already made sure that all the paths are correct, and there is no version conflicts.

As an update I fixed the problem. I used the function below to see the node names;
def list_nodes(frozen_graph_filename):
with tf.io.gfile.GFile(frozen_graph_filename, "rb") as f:
graph_def = tf.compat.v1.GraphDef()
graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
for node in graph_def.node:
    print(node.name)`

After this, I realized I shouldn't give the arg as a string so when I used;
--output_node_names=model/Softmax , it worked.
